# What is the best alternative for Xcode to run the iOS simulator in Windows 11 for React Native cross-platform app development?

Tags: xcode, react-native, cross-platform, ios-simulator

I want to run the iOS simulator on Windows to build my React Native apps. I can't use Xcode because I don't have a Mac or an iPhone. That's why I'm looking for an alternative. I test my Android apps by using Expo Go to mirror my Android phone to Windows, but as I don't have an iPhone and can't mirror it to Windows, I need a simulator to run and test my IOS apps. What is the best alternative for Xcode?

There are few IOS simulator out there for windows and all of them are paid version. Smartface, Appetize etc. As a student I can't afford them for my learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

try this one [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@jonsamp/hello-expo). you have to put your code here but i think it will work fine. there is no other free IOS simulator for windows.

Answer (score 0):

If someone can give you remote access to a mac running Xcode 15.0 or greater you can use that mac as an Xcode Build Server and then run Visual Studio 2022 to develop/debug/test on Windows 11 and then Microsoft provides an iOS Simulator that runs on Windows 11. The only catch: the Microsoft iOS Simulator is just the client for the iOS Simulator running on your Xcode Build Server that you have paired with Visual Studio. So you just have to know someone with a mac that is willing and capable of making their mac accessible to you over the internet.

You can use the Community Edition of Visual Studio 2022 absolutely for free to do all of this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/remote-simulator?view=net-maui-8.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/pair-to-mac?view=net-maui-8.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio